# mpmath and sympy error while packing apk with buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, sympy, buildozer

I am trying to build a apk but it keeps telling me that i need mpmath=>0.19. 
the problem is coming from sympy because when i built the apk without it everything worked as expected. I don't know why it need mpmath even when I include mpmath in the requirement I keep getting the same error. I need help please.

**buildozer.spec**

Command:

buildozer android debug deploy run.

Spec file:
`https://pastebin.com/71maKs5n`

**Full Logs**

```
`https://pastebin.com/EvALr3fW`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I however find a simple solution that worked for me.

I imported locally the modules, by copying them from /usr/local/lib to my app directory where the main.py file and buildozer.spec files are located, and by removing sympy and mpmath from app requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This is a dependency ordering issue, sympy is installed before mpmath but fails because it wants mpmath to be present.

The simplest solution is probably to add a build recipe for mpmath.

Comment: Please how can I add a build recipe for mpmath. I'm  new to kivy and Buildozer.

Comment: Please am still finding this difficult to solve. I added a build recipe for mpmath, it still doesn't solve the problem.